# loop through two sets of array list

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I have a function which receives two list of Flags, 1st is the oldFlags and a newFlags.

what I want to do is, loop through them and check if the newFlags name is present in the oldFlags Name.

if the value is there, replace the object, if not add it to the oldFlags list

```
private fun updateNewFlags(oldOrder: Order, newOrder: Order) {
    newOrder.flags.let {
     
      it.zip(oldOrder.flags).forEach {pair ->
         //WANT TO CHECK IF THE NAME IS PRESENT
          if (pair.first.name == pair.second.name) {
              //IF THE NAME IS THERE REPLACE THE OBJECT WITH THE NEW ONE
              pair.first = pair.second // DONT THINK THIS IS RIGHT?
          } else {
              //ADD THE NEW OBJECT TO THE order.flags
          }
      }
    }
}

public class Flag {
    @Expose protected Object value;

    @Expose protected String name;
}
```

Falg has two parameters, value and a name, name is always unique

what I want to do is, function gets passed the old order and the new order. both can have array of flags

lets say oldOrder has flags and newOrder is sent which might have flags as well, I want to loop through the flags in old and new order and update the oldOrder flags if

- oldOrder flags array list has the newOrder flag, then update the oldOrder Flag
- if not add the newOrder flag to the oldOrder flags arraylist

Can you suggest right approach to do this please

thanks
R

Comment: Could you please share the declaration of the `Order` class?

Comment: do you mean this `public class Order extends ServiceOrder {`

Comment: Yes, basically what are the types of the flags fields etc. You might want to use different structures (like sets) for this instead of ArrayList

Comment: Also are the flags list always aligned like the current code assumes? (with each flag in the same place) Or can the lists be of different sizes/with different order? It feels wrong to only compare things at the same index

Comment: ```public class Flag {
    @Expose protected Object value;

    @Expose protected String name;```

Comment: flag has a name and a value, Name is always unique

Comment: order can be completely different, oldlist and new list can be different, if the old list flag has the same name as the new list flag, then change the whole flag to new one if not add the new flag

Comment: Please update your question instead of answering in comments, it will be more readable with the formatting, and others will see it right away ;)
Do you control these Java classes? I think you should really consider sets in this case instead of lists.

Comment: unclear. please elaborate on what that's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Hello I tried to edit my question with a bit more detail explanation on what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun replaceNamesAndUpdate (newFlags:List<Flags>,oldFlags:List<Flags>):List<Flags>{

 return   oldFlags.toMutableList().also {
        // itarate through oldFlags list 
        newFlags.onEachIndexed { index, newFlag ->
           if (it.find {oldFlag -> 
oldFlag.name == newFlag.name } == null){
               it.add(index,newFlag) // if value from new Flags list is not there add it to old list
           } else {
               it.replace(index,newFlag) // if value is there replace old flag object with object of  same index  from new List
           }
        }
    }
}
```

you can do something like this , but i m not sure if i got your problem correctly

**EDIT** edited some variable names

Comment: hello how did you get `oldflag.name` in the if case please

Comment: may be we can use set instead of replace?

Comment: just use removeat(index)
and add(index,item) instead of replace

Comment: okay will do that check thank you so much